# exception handling for Web page exist or not in blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I am launching page https://www.nasdaq.com/ . After that I am also waiting for 5 sec to load the page. After this I want to check whether the page exist or not, or gets loaded or not then throw the exception. So how and when to use exception handling in this scenario. [see the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptu7D.png). I tried putting recover, resume, exception stage on launch stage as well as on wait stage. But I dont know where to put the exception.

Comment: It may help you to review the concepts contained in the latest version of the Blue Prism Foundation Training on the Documents tab of the [Blue Prism Portal](https://portal.blueprism.com). These topics are all covered within the first few chapters, and provides steady groundwork for your future development activities.

Answer (score 5):

1st of all, don't use arbitrary (fixed) wait stages until it's completely necessary. Use intelligent wait stages instead, which means wait for something to happen and then proceed or throw an exception if it times out. In your case, you can use intelligent wait stage for example to check if the website has been loaded.

[image: wait stage]

When it comes to throwing an exception, in your case I would just simply launch, then wait for the document to be loaded and throw an exception if it times out. See below diagram.

[image: BP diagram]

Also, I would leave retry logic (recover - resume) for the process layer. Object should ideally contain small reusable actions and no business logic, so decisions if and how many times to retry should be taken in the Process.